# Nasm x86_64: Why can't I write and read from the same file?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

I have a problem with file handling in Nasm x86_64.
I have opend correctly the file and i can write into it o read from it, but if I try to read something from the file after i have wrote something into it i don't get anything.
So i get read or write from a file.
The strange thing is that if i first read  write I don't have any problem and everything works fine, so the problem is only when i first write and then read.
Could someone help me to solve this problem and to figure out the cause?

Here is the code to open the file:

```
    mov     rax, SYS_OPEN
    mov     rdi, filename
    mov     rsi, O_CREAT+O_RDWR+O_APPEND
    mov     rdx, 0744o
    syscall
    push    rax
```

Code to close the file:

```
    mov     rax, SYS_CLOSE
    mov     rdi, r11
    syscall
```

Code to print a string:

```
    mov rdx, rax
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, temp
    syscall
```

Code to of getLength (the argument is the string of which I want to get the length):

```
%macro getLength 1
    mov     r10, %1
    mov     r11, r10

    %%begin:
        cmp     byte [r11], 10
        je      %%end
        inc     r11
        jmp     %%begin

    %%end:
        sub     r11, r10
%endmacro
```

The code to write:

```
    getLength msg
    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi, [rsp]
    mov     rsi, msg
    mov     rdx, r11
    syscall
```

Code to read:

```
    mov     rax, SYS_READ
    mov     rdi, [rsp]
    mov     rsi, temp    ;buffer to store the string read
    mov     rdx, 10
    syscall
```

Both the code to read and the code to write works perfectly alone, the problem is when I use the code to read after the code to write.

So this code works.

```
    %include "./standardlib.inc"

section .data
    filename db "./file.txt", 0
    msg     db "hello", 10

section .bss
    temp    resb 10

section .text
    global _start:

    _start:
    mov     rax, SYS_OPEN
    mov     rdi, filename
    mov     rsi, O_CREAT+O_RDWR+O_APPEND
    mov     rdx, 0744o
    syscall
    push    rax

    mov     rax, SYS_READ
    mov     rdi, [rsp]
    mov     rsi, temp
    mov     rdx, 10
    syscall

    mov rdx, rax
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, temp
    syscall

    getLength msg

    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi, [rsp]
    mov     rsi, msg
    mov     rdx, r11
    syscall

    mov     rax, SYS_CLOSE
    mov     rdi, r11
    syscall

    exit
```

This coe doesn't work:

```
    %include "./standardlib.inc"

section .data
    filename db "./file.txt", 0
    msg     db "hello", 10

section .bss
    temp    resb 10

section .text
    global _start:

    _start:
    mov     rax, SYS_OPEN
    mov     rdi, filename
    mov     rsi, O_CREAT+O_RDWR+O_APPEND
    mov     rdx, 0744o
    syscall
    push    rax

    getLength msg

    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi, [rsp]
    mov     rsi, msg
    mov     rdx, r11
    syscall

    mov     rax, SYS_READ
    mov     rdi, [rsp]
    mov     rsi, temp
    mov     rdx, 10
    syscall

    mov rdx, rax
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, temp
    syscall

    mov     rax, SYS_CLOSE
    mov     rdi, r11
    syscall

    exit
```

So i understood that I have to use lseek to return to the beginning of the file.
Is this a good invocation for sys_lseek?

```
    mov rax, 8        ;sys_lseek syscall ID
    mov rdi, [rsp]    ;file descriptor
    mov rsi, 0        ;The offset
    mov rdx, 0        ;I imagine the value of SEEK_SET
```

[sys_lseek](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99706&seqNum=6)

I suppose that the offset value is wrong and I should have used ftell to find it, but I can't figure out how to call it.

[ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/)

Comment: You don't show us the contents of `./standardlib.inc` and in particular how `getlength` is defined (I assume a macro). Not sure it is returning a value in r11? Something seems fishy there. Can you show us how `getlength` appears in that .inc file?

Comment: Why do you open the file in append mode?  What do you expect to read from the file after appending to it?  If you don't know what append mode does, read the man page for `open(2)` first.

Comment: Reading the docs for [write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write), we see: *writing takes place at the current file offset, and the file offset is incremented by the number of bytes actually written*.  Since you are doing a write to the end of the file (due to O_APPEND), then the file position after the write will also be the end of the file.  And there's nothing more to read, cuz, well, it's at the end of the file.  Perhaps what you need is [lseek](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I didn't put the code of standardlib because I know that getLength works fine since I used it in various situation at it has never gave me proble, and if it had problem probably also the execution a single read to file without having written to it before would have raised issues.

Comment: @LeonardoDeFaveri : You may use it, but the rest of us don't so you make us guess that it is actually working as expected. Because it is missing along with the defines, this isn't an [mcve] so you have to make us guess as to all the problem(s) that may exist.

Comment: @fuz I was just trying to work in an hypotethical situation that I think I would be probable in the future.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think that a call to lseek to return to the beginning of the file may resolve the proble, but how can I call it (Please see the body of my question to see what I've tried)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch ok I will put the code of getLength.

Comment: @LeonardoDeFaveri Refer to the man page of `lseek` for what arguments it takes.

Comment: @fuz ok, I understood that the offset it my actual position into the file, and that in my program since I has written something my offset is at the end of the file, so I can't read anything. But I don't understand how to find the offset value.

Comment: @LeonardoDeFaveri Do an `lseek` with `SEEK_CUR` and an offset of 0.  Then observe the return value.

Comment: @fuz I did it and it returned in rax the value 45, which may be coorect since 45 is the number of characters written into the file.

Comment: @LeonardoDeFaveri Should be correct then.

Comment: Proble solved, thank you @fuz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the file are read sequentially, after a call to sys_read in append mode the cursor is moved to the end of the file, so if you try to read from that position you won't read anything.

To solve this problem you have to reposition the cursor at the beginning of the file.

To do that you can use the lseek system call.

```
    mov     rax, 8        ;system call Id for sys_lseek
    mov     rdi, [rsp]    ;file descriptor
    mov     rsi, 0        ;offset value, so number of characters to move the cursor
    mov     rdx, 0        ;It indicates the initial position from which move the cursor, in this case the value 0 indicates that the initial position is the beginning of the file
    syscall
```

After a call to this system call the cursor position will be at the beginning of the file and you will be able to read from it.

Comment: Also note that if you know what position you want to read from, you can simply use a `pread()` (positional read) system call instead of `lseek` + `read`.  `pread` doesn't move the fd's file position.  But if you want to rewind the file position for potentially multiple `read`s, then yes you want to use `lseek`.